# How to correctly prefix a list of dependencies in a Makefile rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My `Makefile` has rules that apply to every subdirectory. When one such rule has dependencies, I obviously want those dependencies to

1. When mentioned in the dependencies, they should bind to the same path as the target file.
2. When mentioned in the rule, they should use the same path as the target.

The best that I can come up with is the example below. It works, but looks verbose and hard to read. Is there a more programatic way of approaching this?

```
BUILDDIR = build
BCFILES = file1.bc file2.bc file3.bc 

...

BCFILES_STARED = $(patsubst %, */$(BUILDDIR)/%, $(BCFILES))
*/$(BUILDDIR)/my_program.bc: $(BCFILES_STARED) */build
    llvm-link $(patsubst %, $(@D)/%, $(BCFILES)) -o $@
```

Comment: Does `*` stand for all sub-directories of the current directory?

Comment: In general globbing / wildcards are not appropriate for using in makefiles.  Whenever you find yourself reaching for them, it _usually_ means that you're misunderstanding something.  There are a limited set of situations where they can be helpful (although a robust system probably would never rely on them).  Having wildcards in target names, in particular, is 99.9999% of the time going to be wrong.  Consider: a wildcard matches files on the disk.  But a target is something _you want to build_.  So it won't exist on the disk, normally.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes, I would like `*` to represent any of the sub-directories of the current directory.

Comment: @MadScientist Agree that this is not the way to go. How could I make it better?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when you say "it works", you're not correct.  It may appear to give results that you're expecting in some situations, but it's going to fail in other situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not clear on what you want to do.  But maybe it's something like:

```
BUILDDIR = build
BCFILES = file1.bc file2.bc file3.bc 

SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)
PROGRAMS := $(patsubst %/.,%/$(BUILDDIR)/my_program.bc,$(SUBDIRS))

all: $(PROGRAMS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:

%/my_program.bc: $$(addprefix $$(@D)/,$$(BCFILES))
          @mkdir -p $(@D)
          llvm-link $^ -o $@
```

You can look in the GNU Make manual for details on [wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) and [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html).

Comment: That's it. I didn't know about second expansion and that's what I needed.